# log4j JDBC appender in Talend

Tags: java, postgresql, logging, log4j, talend

In Talend Studio, I can get log4 logs on console but I want them in database.
So I added the following properties to log4j using the 'project setting' tab on the Talend Studio:

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
  <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Sample"/>
  <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <param name="user" value="postgres"/>
  <param name="password" value="root"/>
  <param name="sql" value="INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%x','%d','%C','%p','%m')"/>`
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="log4j.rootLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="DB"/>
</logger>
```

But got the following error:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 62 and column 23
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "
(renderer*,throwableRenderer?,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,
(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)".
log4j:WARN No such property [url] in org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.
log4j:ERROR Failed to load driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well, I an not getting this error now. But after running job, there is no log in the table.

Comment: Did you add the postgresql jar to Talend ? Could you try by specifiying the column names in your insert query : `INSERT INTO LOGS (message, priority..etc) VALUES (...)` ?
Could you try to execute that query directly in a postgresql client and see if you get any errors ?
Also, it looks like the url needs to be in uppercase: URL

Comment: Yes, I made url to Uppercase. Also tried specifying column names like `<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> <param name="ConversionPattern"  value="INSERT INTO logs (user_id, dated, logger, level, message) VALUES ( '%x','%d','%C','%p','%m' )" /> </layout> ` But no logs are written in table

Comment: If you execute your insert query using sample values in a postgresql client, does it work ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO logs (user_id, dated, logger, level, message) VALUES ( '%x','%d','%C','%p','%m' )` this is giving error that '%d' is in invalid format. It is having datatype 'date'. so fired query `INSERT INTO logs (user_id, dated, logger, level, message) VALUES ( 'test','2018-02-15','test','test','test')` and it work. it does insert record.

Comment: Also does the schema for log table be modified? or it must be like 'user_id, dated, logger, level, message' this only, can I add new column to it like 'custom_message'